# Flutter create image and text inside the card

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: new Scaffold(
          body: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                  child: Image(
                    image: new AssetImage('assets/cardbg.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                color: Colors.white,
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              ),
              new Text('hjsdgshagdjadh'),
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

I am creating carview with Image and textview.i want text on the left side of a card and circular image on the right side of a card and i want to set background image for the card.Below the card i want Listview with text and checkbox.If select any checkbox the selected item should appear on the right side of the cardview.In android i did all these things but i don't know how to implement the same in flutter.

Comment: can you paste the screenshot of desired layout you are looking?

Comment: please check my above code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need help on your screen's layout. Have you tried anything so far and did you encounter any particular issues? I suggest going through the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout) to learn more about working with layouts in Flutter.

For your use case, here's a general view on how we can lay out the widgets on the screen. Containers for alignment and padding won't be included in this overview to keep it simple.

```
Column
- Card
  - Column
    - Row
      - Column
        - Text
        - Text
      - Image
    - Text
- ListView
  - Card
    - Row
      - Text
      - Checkbox
```

> If select any checkbox the selected item should appear on the right side of the cardview.

I'm not quite sure on what the desired output when the checkbox is ticked. If you can provide more details, I may be able to provide some guidance.

In this sample, values from the checkbox are stored in a HashMap. You may change it as you see fit, depending on your use case.

Here's a sample code that you can play with.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Map<String, bool> checkboxValues = {
    'List CheckBox 1': false,
    'List CheckBox 2': false,
    'List CheckBox 3': false,
    'List CheckBox 4': false,
    'List CheckBox 5': false,
    'List CheckBox 6': false,
    'List CheckBox 7': false,
    'List CheckBox 8': false,
    'List CheckBox 9': false,
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text('Text 1'),
                              Container(
                                height: 24,
                                width: 0,
                              ),
                              Text('Text 2'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Image(
                          height: 60,
                          image: AssetImage('assets/image.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 24, 0, 0),
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text('Text 3'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            semanticContainer: true,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            elevation: 5,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: ListView(
              children: checkboxValues.keys.map((key) {
                return Card(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(key),
                        Checkbox(
                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                            setState(() {
                              // store new val of key on HashMap
                              checkboxValues[key] = value;
                            });
                          },
                          value: checkboxValues[key],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How the app looks when running

[image: demo]